# Excel Formula on : How to compare multiple columns in excel

Tags: ms-office, development

I am trying to compare multiple columns in excel like below

```
A          B          C          D         E            F
HN_1     1.1.1.1     Comp_1    HN_1     1.1.1.1       Comp_1
HN_2     2.2.2.2     Comp_1    HN_2     3.3.3.3       Comp_2
HN_3     3.3.3.3     Comp_2    HN_3       N/A         Comp_3
HN_4     4.4.4.4     Comp_3    
HN_5     3.3.3.3     Comp_2    HN_4     4.4.4.4       Comp_3


a. Compare A & D (if true return "Same Name Only")

b. IF A = D then compare B = E (return "Same Name, IP ") 

c. IF A = D && B = E then compare C = F  (return "Same Name, IP, Comp")
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Show us the work which fails for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do the first one, then you can use and() to sort the other two:

```
=IF(A1=D1,"Same Name Only","")
```

Hint:

```
AND(A1+D1,B1+E1)
```

Well, see

[image]

Comment: It is not working Mike.

Comment: I want to search like

A           B           C            D            E             F               G
N1        1.1        cmp1      N1         1.1          cmp1
N2         2.2       cmp2      N4         1.0          cmp1

Comment: I took your data and changed a couple of values to check the 3 options...

Comment: Hi Mike, this solved the problem thanks you